# Dispaly time current position media in TextBlock - Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I develop an application in Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight that play media with MediaElement. So, i want display time current position media in TextBlock during media is playing, How to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DispatcherTimer to update the textblock. Like this:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
timer.Start();
```

To get current position, in `timer_Tick` function, use `yourPlayer.Position.ToString()`:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock.Text = yourPlayer.Position.ToString();
    }
```